# Installation of a module in requirements.txt fails on not finding another module defined there

Tags: python, pip, requirements.txt

I'm installing python modules using `requirements.txt` while building docker containers.

```
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
```

One of the packages in `requirements.txt` is dependent on `numpy` and `pip` fails saying `You must install numpy before installing aeneas`. But the `numpy` module is defined before the failing module in the `requirements.txt`.

```
numpy==1.15.3
aeneas==1.7.3.0
```

How is this possible? Aren't the modules installed in the order they're written in the file? How to solve this?

Comment: What is the package in question ? and what is the distro of the container ?

Comment: No minimal verifiable example, and your own paraphrasal of the error message?  I think you can do better than that.  Include a complete minimal requirements file and Dockerfile that causes the error and also include the _exact_ error not your interpretation of it.  Otherwise, we're just guessing.

Comment: looks like a version mismatch, https://github.com/readbeyond/aeneas/blob/master/requirements.txt#L3 no? but you're installing `numpy 1.15.3`

Comment: You won't be able to install both packages in one pass because building `aeneas` requires `numpy` to be installed. Installing from requirements is the same as calling `pip install numpy aeneas` whereas `aeneas` can only be installed by splitting the installation `pip install numpy && pip install aeneas`.

Comment: @hoefling So there cannot be any dependent modules in one requirements file?

Comment: No, because `pip install -r reqs` is essentially the same as calling `cat reqs | xargs pip install`. It will pass the complete list of packages to a single `pip install`. If you need a somewhat future-proof solution, you can do smth like `RUN grep numpy requirements.txt | xargs pip install && pip install -r requirements.txt` which will preinstall `numpy` if defined, then install the rest as usual.

Comment: Alternatively, you can switch to `pipenv` which supports retrying failed installation of dependencies; here is an answer I gave to a similar problem with `kivy + cython` dependency: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46620668/2650249).